# Highcharts nodejs many colors

Tags: node.js, highcharts

ColorCount and adding colors to the data [] to a stackedbar chart do not allow many colors on the stacked bar, a limit of 10. HOw to get more colors ? The latest nodejs install was recently done.

Answer (score 0):

Color limit for styled version of Highcharts can be increased using the [`colorCount`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.colorCount) of `chart`.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        colorCount: 12
    },
    ...
});
```

Next in CSS you could set colors for `.highcharts-color-10` and more (up to 11, because 12 is the new limit for this demo).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gqjy2j19/

Comment: the colorIndex does not go beyond 10 :( when clicking

Comment: yes in jsfiddle the color index goes above 10, but not with http-server locally

Comment: the new colors show when locally tested, but the colorIndex remains max 10 ?

Comment: @markrobertspowage Please recreate the problem in JSFiddle or provide another way to test your issue.

Comment: the free version has 12 high stack, so that was the trick , to keep stack under max size

Comment: what api can read the stackbar 'name' that shows in the mousehover other than the colorIndex

Comment: @markrobertspowage Please explain what do you mean by "the stackbar 'name' that shows in the mousehover". Is this something related to [the tooltip](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/tooltip)? Maybe you could add an image of the problem.